# IE9+ background-position: left/right not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I want to position a background of an label element to the left but it is never on the left in ie9+.

My code is similar to this

```
label {
       background-image: url('some-image.svg');
       background-position: left center;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       padding-left: 20px;
}
```

This is working in all the browsers but (of course) in the ie9+, strangely it is working in ie8.

I hope someone can help because I can't simple position it fixed with a negative background offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. It was related to the SVG Images I was using in newer versions of IE and Safari that caused the error. It seems that SVGs always have a with of 100% even as backgrounds.

So If you need to positon an image for eg a checkbox or radiobutton like me, you should have a fallback to PNGs for such Browsers.